# Numpy calculating corrcoef for large multispectral images

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

I'm trying to calculate Correlation coefficients of one pixel to a whole image.
I have the following code that works

```
#load picture from serialized data 21 channels, ~500 x ~900 px
pic=pickle.load(open('hyper.p','rb'))

#prepare result table
result=zeros((pic.shape[1],pic.shape[2]))

#one pixel(10,10) from the image, all the channels
pixel=pic[:,10,10]

#for all pixels
for x in xrange(pic.shape[1]):
    for y in xrange(pic.shape[2]):
            #calculate correlation coeficient between one pixel and current pixel
        miniciurek = corrcoef(pixel,pic[:,x,y])
        result[x,y] = miniciurek[1,0]

imshow(result)
colorbar()
show()
```

code above works, but it takes a significant amount of time to complete,
I heard there is a better way of calculating the values, a way that would do a batch calculation at once, so I came up with such a solution:

```
#flattern the (21,~500,~900) matrix into a (21,500*900) matrix
orka = pic.reshape((pic.shape[0],pic.shape[1]*pic.shape[2],))

#create a matrix full of pixels same as the chosen one
pur = zeros((pic.shape[0],pic.shape[1]*pic.shape[2]))
for a in xrange(pic.shape[0]):
    pur[a,:].fill(krzywa1[a])

#at this point I have two (21,~300000) matrixes
tempResult = corrcoef(pur ,orka ,0)
```

I'm stuck at this point because corrcoef tries to allocate a (600k,600k) matrix, which fails. The values I need are in one of the diagonals of this huge matrix.

1. Is there any way to avoid generating such amounts of data while using corrcoef? Slicing image into 1000 pixel batches and feeding them to corrcoef takes longer then just using single pixels!
2. Does python/numpy have any batch execution routines that could speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to speed this up using the corrcoef function. But, if you know that the corrcoeff function is simply calculating the [Pearson's correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient), it's easy to write your own code to do the same. Here's a function that does what you want:

```
import numpy as np

def correlation(pixel, image):
    c, m, n = image.shape
    image = image.reshape(c, m * n)

    pixel_mean = pixel.mean()
    pixel_std = pixel.std()
    means = image.mean(0)
    stds = image.std(0)

    # calculate the covariance between `pixel` and each image pixel
    covs = np.dot(pixel - pixel_mean, image - means) / float(c)

    # calculate Pearson's correlation coefficient
    corr = covs / (pixel_std * stds)
    return corr.reshape(m, n)

# generate a random image to test
c = 21
m = 500
n = 900
image = np.random.randn(c, m, n)
corr = correlation(image[:,10,10], image)

# check an arbitrary point to make sure it works
assert np.allclose(corr[302, 411], 
                   np.corrcoef(image[:,10,10], image[:,302,411])[0,1])
```

This calculates the correlation coefficients between one pixel and each other pixel in the image. Though if your ultimate goal is to calculate the correlation between each pixel and every other pixel in the image, you will run out of memory (you'd need about 1.5 terabytes just to store all the coefficients, for the given image size 500 x 900).